# On Swift, how to retrive name and other data when login with Facebook and Parse with FBSDK

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, fbsdk

Can't get the user's name or email when login with Facebook via Parse. I should have set everything else properly in the AppDelegate.

When I login with my email, my User class works, and can use data I registered with. When I try to login via Facebook, I only got the long alphanumerical string as username and stop. I'd like to retrive name, foto, birth and city.

**In my User.swift file I'got this:**

```
import Foundation

struct User
{
    let username : String
    let address : String
}
```

**This is my login button:**

```
@IBAction func facebookLoginAction(sender: UIButton)
    {
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_about_me", "user_birthday"]) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let user = user
            {
                if user.isNew
                {
                    println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                }
                else
                {
                    println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                }
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
            }
        }
    }
```

**tried this too, but doesn't work:**

```
    func getUserInfo() {
//        if let session = PFFacebookUtils.session() {
        if let session = PFFacebookUtils.facebookLoginManager() {
            if session.isOpen {
                println("session is open")
                FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    //println("done me request")
                    if error != nil {
                        println("facebook me request - error is not nil :(")
                    } else {
                        println("facebook me request - error is nil :) ")
                        let urlUserImg = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(result.objectID)/picture?type=large"
                        let firstName = result.first_name
                        let lastName = result.last_name
                    }
                })
            }
        } else {
            //let user:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()
            //println("ohooo \(user)")
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is working code I use to get Facebook information with Parse. The function is called after successful authentication with `user.isNew`. It can also be called even if the user isn't new to make sure you have the most up-to-date information when they log back in.

```
func loadFacebookData() {
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email, name, id"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            let error = error!.userInfo["error"] as! String
        }
        else {
            if let userName = result.valueForKey("name") as? String, email = result.valueForKey("email") as? String, id = result.valueForKey("id") as? String {
                let pictureURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/\(id)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1")!
                let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
                let query = PFUser.query()
                query!.whereKey("email", equalTo: email)
                query!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (oldUser: PFObject?, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil && oldUser != nil {
                        let error = error!.userInfo["error"] as! String
                    }
                    else {
                        self.setFacebookInfo(user, userEmail: email, userName: userName, pictureURL: pictureURL)
                    }
                })
            }
        }

    }
}
```