# Store and Save Facebook Data Using Parse Using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I have a Facebook sign in button on my app. How can I get Parse to save the Facebook user as a parse user and save the data (email address) into the Parse Database?

Below is the code for my Facebook button.

```
   @IBAction func didTapFacebookConnect(sender: AnyObject) {
    let permissions = [ "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" ]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {    

                print ("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

            } else {
                print ("User logged in through Facebook!")

            }
        } else {
            print ("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of question I answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065748/on-swift-how-to-retrive-name-and-other-data-when-login-with-facebook-and-parse/33067236#33067236

Answer (score -2):

Create one custom file using NSObject base controller.
And pass value there. and in .m file store value in user default.

Comment: This for one does not answer the question, and two does not use the language the question is asking about.